# Adding <label> tag causes textbox icon to move to new line. How to prevent this?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using default Bootstrap 3 css however when I put an image label next to a textbox it doesn't show next to it but renders on a new line.

[image]
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d234/cn8e55m0/6/

```
 <div class="container body-content">
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class="panel-title">
                Month
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="MonthStartDate">Month Start Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="input-group date">

                            <input class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" id="MonthStartDate" name="MonthStartDate" type="text"></input>
                            <label  for="MonthStartDate">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span> 
                            </label>
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MonthStartDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take note: I had to add a label around my image span in order for it to trigger a datepicker popup, so I can't just remove it. However when that label opening and closing tag, then it renders correctly.

How can I still have the label but have it render correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I had two labels. Both had 
    `for="MonthStartDate`

It seems the 2nd one inherited the first one's `col-md-2` causing it to appear on the first line.

Renaming the `for="unique"` to a unique value  fixed my problem